# How to force the Drupal form to clear previous results

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal-7

Recently im working on a project and im trying to generate form elements with the help of ajax technology (implementing a form with codes). the situation is that the user should be able to select from a list of options and then due to his select another list of options should be appeared, then due to his/her select from the second sets of options he/she should see the third series of options. now the problem is that when the user tries to change the first option in the first set, the second option will be regenerate but the third one still sticks on the page. I was trying to use the form_sate['rebuild'] = TRUE 
but it did not work and all form elements disappeared. can any one help me to see which code should be implemented and where it should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's almost impossible to help, except to say check out the [examples modules](http://drupal.org/project/examples), specifically the `ajax_example` module.

The basic principle is that you need a `<div>` container surrounding your 2nd and 3rd select elements, which will be replaced by the `#ajax` set on the first element. Then you need another container inside that one surrounding only the 3rd select element, which will be replaced by the `#ajax` set on the 2nd select element.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

well.. the form page may contains previous values because of $_POST fields variables..

for example if I want to display clear "add" form on POST submit,
I do this tric to clear drupal previous form values via ajax:

```
<?php
// AJAX POST handler...
....
$my_form = drupal_render(drupal_get_form("the_form", ...));
$errors = form_get_errors();
if (!$errors) {
  // re-render clean form, unset your POST fields....
  unset($_POST['link_path']);
  unset($_POST['link_title']);
  unset($_POST['parent']);
  unset($_POST['weight']);
  $my_form = drupal_render(drupal_get_form("the_form", ...));
}
?>
```